# Sharing I2C driver by kernel and userspace

Tags: linux-kernel, alsa, device-tree

My hardware design uses the same I2C controller for chips controlled by kernel modules (DAC and ADC in sound ASoC) and for devices I want to control from userspace (I2C port expanders -> relays). Can I use the controller in the ASoC devicetree files and use it from user-space libraries at the same time? If so, how can I guard/lock access to the controller between kernel and userspace to avoid clashing I2C transactions?

Comment: You can use the [i2c-dev](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html) interface, together with the `libi2c` library.

Comment: Ian, thanks a lot. What I do not know is if I can use the same I2C controller via i2c-dev in userspace to control some I2C devices and assign it (via devicetree ) to control several ASoC codecs in their kernel modules at the same time, without having to worry about guarding I2C transactions somehow. E.g. in rust (embedded-rust) access to multiple devices via single I2C controller in multiple threads must be guarded by https://docs.rs/shared-bus/0.2.2/shared_bus/ . Here it's also about concurrent access (userspace vs. kernel driver) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use the same controller. After opening the /dev/i2c-*N* device, you need to set the slave address using the `I2C_SLAVE` ioctl. (It will fail if the slave address is already in use, but note that some devices will respond to more than one slave address, so be careful!) The kernel locks the I2C adapter's during the transaction, so there won't be any clashes due to multiple transactions on the bus at the same time.

Comment: I missed a word out: "The kernel locks the I2C adapter's [bus] during the transaction".